# How to get back to old Azure Logic Apps UI?

Tags: user-interface, azure-logic-apps

For some reason, the look and feel of Azure Logic Apps has changed in my tenant. Its very terse and missing some simple functionality like "Rename" actions.

[image]

If I open Logic Apps in other tenants I have access to, it looks much better (very similar to Power Automate)

**How do I get back to the old look and feel?**

Answer (score 0):

The new designer is rolled out for a few percentage of users. If you want to revert back to the old designer then as a workaround you can use the below link, but this only works for consumption. For standard logic apps, it is always using the new designer.

https://portal.azure.com/?feature.experimentation=false&feature.experimentationflights=v2cf